# Fréchet filter on $\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

Define the Fréchet filter for a regular cardinal $\kappa$ in the following way:

> $\mathcal{F}(\kappa) = \{X \in \kappa \mid |\kappa - X| < \kappa\}$.

I am trying to show that the previous construction indeed yields a filter and I am having a problem with showing that it is closed under intersections.

I know, that classically the Fréchet filter is defined for $\omega$ (cofinite sets), so it is easy to show that this is a filter. But my trouble is extending the proof for any regular cardinal. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: How do you show it for $\omega$?

Comment: Do you know that the union of two sets of cardinality less than $\kappa$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$? The assumption that $\kappa$ is regular is irrelevant here.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Hi! I understood that this is needed here, but I did not know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X, Y\in\mathcal{F}(\kappa)$. By definition, $\kappa_X=|\kappa-X|<\kappa$ and $\kappa_Y=|\kappa-Y|<\kappa$. Now note that

$\kappa-(X\cap Y)=(\kappa- X)\cup(\kappa- Y)$.

Therefore,

$|\kappa-(X\cap Y)|= |(\kappa- X)\cup(\kappa- Y)|\leq \kappa_X+\kappa_Y$

and $\kappa_X+\kappa_Y <\kappa$. So $X\cap Y\in\mathcal{F}(\kappa)$.